# How should I improve this lazy loading pattern in PhP?

Tags: php, lazy-loading

```
static $searchQuery="nothing";

if ($searchQuery=="nothing")
{
    if ($referral=="")
    {
        $referral=referrer();
    }
    $searchQuery=getSearchQuery($referral);
}
return $searchQuery;
```

Basically I need to initialize $searchQuery with something.

I can initialize it with "" but the value of $searchQuery is often legitimately "".

So how should I initialize it? ""? Nil? Null? array()? What?

I can also use

```
static $result;
if  (isset($result))
{
    return $result;
}
```

but I got warning because $result is not defined.

Comment: You could ditch the `static` for starters.

Comment: what? Of course I have to use static.

Comment: Why's that? Why do you think you need static?

Comment: Please start by explaining *what* you are trying to do. (Leave implementation details aside)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's up to you, but you need to be careful with PHP's loose typing. I prefer `NULL`, and I would write that code as:

```
static $searchQuery = NULL;

if( is_null($searchQuery) ) {
    if( emtpy($referral) ) {
        $referral=referrer();
    }
    $searchQuery=getSearchQuery($referral);
}
return $searchQuery;
```

Comment: Is NULL equal to 0? 0 is a possible value to return by the way.

Comment: @JimThio In PHP's usual 'lazy' comparison `NULL`, `0`, `"0"`, and `""` are all equivalent to `false`. `is_null()` is a strict comparison equivalent to `$value === NULL` and will only return true if the value is `NULL`.